# Get name of labeling rule with Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I want to access the name of a rule in the rule-based labeling of a layer in QGIS via Python.

Getting all the attributes works for me, also the preview text. But I didn't find the property to get the name of a rule. Here a short code example:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
labeling = layer.labeling()
    
for rule in labeling.subProviders():
    print(labeling.settings(rule).Show)
    print(labeling.settings(rule).Priority)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `description` method of class `QgsRuleBasedLabeling.Rule`.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
labeling = layer.labeling()

for rule in labeling.rootRule().children():
    print(rule.description())
```

[image]